# .htaccess URL rewrite - check for condition and append a parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

What would the rewrite code look like please for **redirecting this**:

[https://example.com/cart/?coupon-code=[dynamic_code]](https://example.com/cart/?coupon-code=%5Bdynamic_code%5D) (e.g. https://example.com/cart/?coupon-code=abcd)

**to this**:

[https://example.com/cart/?coupon-code=[dynamic_code]&add-to-cart=123](https://example.com/cart/?coupon-code=%5Bdynamic_code%5D&add-to-cart=123) (e.g. https://example.com/cart/?coupon-code=abcd&add-to-cart=123)

The *https://example.com/cart/* part of the URL and the *coupon-code* parameter must be present, and only then the static *add-to-cart=123* should be appended

Thank you so much (I've perused other questions, and drafted something, but I'm afraid it's so off, I thought I'd rather not post any code here, and see if someone would be kind enough to reply).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obviously need one condition and one rewriting rule...

If you are only interested in preserving that single query argument:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)coupon-code=([^&]*)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?cart/? /cart/?coupon-code=%1&add-to-cart=123 [END]
```

In case you want to preserve potential other query args that version should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)coupon-code=[^&]*(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?cart/? /cart/?%{QUERY_STRING}&add-to-cart=123 [END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server and activated for that host or location.

Comment: thank you so much for this; I'm having some issues with .htaccess changes not taking hold so I'm working through that right now (never seen this before, but this is a server and website I'm helping somebody out with); anyway, just wanted to say thanks, and I'll report back how this is working out. In the meantime, may I ask what the first question mark in the RewriteRule is for? I.e., why is it not just ^/cart/?

Comment: RewriteRules act different depending on where they are implemented: in _distributed_ configuration files (".htaccess") it is the _relative_ path of the requested URL that is matched by that pattern, in the central configuration it is the _absolute_ path used for matching. Using `^/?cart` in your matching patterns you implement rules that work in both situations which makes your code more portable. If you do not like that you can use `^cart`, but `^/cart` simply won't match in distributed configuration files.